# Determining what memory/values a remote application accesses/changes?

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory, memory-management

Lets take an example here which is known everywhere in the IT world:

We have a game, for example solitaire, and someone makes and releases a trainer for it that your moves are always '0'.

How do I programatically determine which adresses and what values that "hack" changes?

What way would be the best, if this is possible?

- From within the game [injecting/loading my own dll?]
- By intercepting traffic between the hack and target process with my own process?

I ask this question because of 2 things:

- Protect an application from being "hacked" (at least by the [script kiddies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie))
- Reverse engineer a trainer (so you don't have to [reinvent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) / avoid [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Some broken attempts may be setting two addresses and then comparing them (they will find the other address though). Or they can simply remove your compare call.

They can alter any protection function that you use to "programatically determine" to always return false results. They can do anything to your executable, so there is no way.

Unless you hook the kernel functions that open your process to modify the memory. But that is also breakable and if I am not wrong you need to get your "protection kernel driver" digitally signed now.

There is another way in which you load a DLL in every running and newly spawned processes (which will probably alert antiviruses about your program being a virus), with that DLL you hook OpenProcess (and if there is another alternative to it, that too) functions in each process and check if its targeted at your program, and prevent it if so. Search about function hooking. I believe there was something called "MS Detour" or something for it.

And still, the game will not even be close to safe.

To sum up, no way is good to protect your game locally. If you are storing scores or something you should create a server program and client should report every move to server.

Even then, they can create a bot to automatically respond to server. Then the best you can do is somehow verify it is a human that is playing. (maybe captcha or comparing the solving speed with human avarage?)

Comment: and what about the reverse engineering question? for example if I want to get the adresses from a trainer and make my own better version? (avoiding the NIH syndrom)

Comment: This doesn't answer his actual question, it's more of a comment on his reasons for asking it.

Comment: hm the DLL idea sounds  great for reverse engineering a trainer, IDA + HexRays didn't perform really well.... in my entire lifetime. I'm no asm guy hehe.

Comment: Can't upvote lol ;> used all votes. anyway waiting for more answer, too soon to determine a final answer :p

Comment: @GamErix Sure, wait. It's been really long time since I've done any research on this subject, all I remember is I wish there was no OpenProcess function ever. Maybe I forgot some things.